# Why does this function give me errors in MDCard KivyMD

Tags: kivymd, python-3.10, md-card

Here is my MDCard in .kv file. This MDCard is the same .kv file where Screen manager is located.

```
<MD3Card>
   orientation: "vertical"
   size_hint: None, None
   size: "117dp", "117dp"
   focus_behavior: True
   md_bg_color: (44/255, 44/255, 44/255, 1)
   unfocus_color: 0.172, 0.172, 0.172, 1
   focus_color: "darkgrey"
   padding: "7dp", "7dp", "7dp", 0
   on_release: root.cards_activities()

   FitImage:
      source: root.source
      size_hint: None, None
      size: "58dp", "55dp"
      pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .05}

   MDRelativeLayout:

     MDLabel:
        text: root.text
        halign: "center"
        font_name: "assets/fonts/01389_ALD721L.ttf"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: (217/255, 208/255, 208/255, 1)

<AllGimScreen>

   MDBoxLayout:
      md_bg_color: (44/255, 44/255, 44/255, 1)

      ScreenManager:
         id: screen_manager

         MDScreen:
            name: "root_page"

            MDBoxLayout:
                id: box_layout
                orientation: "vertical"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                MDRelativeLayout:
                    id: relative_layout
                    size_hint_y: .30

                    MDTextField:
                        id: search_field
                        hint_text: "Search gim"
                        mode: "rectangle"
                        width: "350"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
                        size_hint_x: None
                    MDIconButton:
                        icon: "magnify"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .85, "center_y": .4}
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        text_color: (217/255, 208/255, 208/255, 1)
                        on_release: 
                           root.searching(search_field.text)

                MDScrollView:
                    id: searched_view
                    do_scroll_y: True
                    do_scroll_x: False

                    MDList:
                        id: searched_list
                        cols: 3
                        rows: 41
                        spacing: "18dp"
                        padding: "24dp"

                        MD3Card:
                            id: gim 1
                            source: "assets/images/Gim 1-img.png"
                            text: "Gim 1"

                        MD3Card:
                            id: gim 2
                            source: "assets/images/Gim 2-img.png"
                            text: "Gim 2"

                        MD3Card:
                            id: gim 3
                            source: "assets/images/Gim 3-img.png"
                            text: "Gim 3"

        MDScreen:
           name: "gim_page"

           MDIconButton:
              icon: "arrow-left"
              pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
              on_release:
                 screen_manager.current = "root_page"

           MDLabel:
              id: gim_label
              text: "Gim activity's"
              pos_hint: {"center_y": .95}
              halign: "center"
              font_name: "assets/fonts/01389_ALD721L.ttf"
              font_size: "20sp"
              theme_text_color: "Custom"
              text_color: (217/255, 208/255, 208/255, 1)

           MDScrollView:
              do_scroll_y: True
              do_scroll_x: False
              size_hint_y: .9

              MDList:
                 id: activity_list
                 cols: 3
                 rows: 41
                 spacing: "18dp"
                 padding: "24dp"
```

Here are my classes:

```py
class MD3Card(MDCard):

    source = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
```

```py
class AllGimScreen(MDScreen):

    def cards_activities(self):
        self.ids.screen_manager.current = "gim_page"
```

When I run the code, I get the error:

```
 on_release: root.cards_activities()
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'MD3Card' object has no attribute 'cards_activities'
```

Even when I move the function to class `MD3Card`:

```py
class MD3Card(MDCard):

    source = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()

    def cards_activities(self):
        self.ids.screen_manager.current = "gim_page"
```

I get this error:

```
 self.ids.screen_manager.current = "gim_page"
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
```

How to make function to get screen = "gim_page"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I wrote directly to the behavior of the MD3Card button:

```
MD3Card:
   id: gim 1
   source: "assets/images/Gim 1-img.png"
   text: "Gim 1"
   on_release: root.cards_activities(root)
```

This is function:

```
def cards_activities(self, widget):
   self.ids.screen_manager.current = "gim_page"
```

Then when I'll try to go to gim_page I'll use this function where I'll find
on_release atribut:

```
def searching(self, search_field):
    if search_field != "":
        self.ids.search_label.text = search_field
        self.ids.screen_manager.current = "search_results"
        for key, val in self.ids.items():
            if search_field.lower() in key:
                card = MD3Card(
                    source=val.source,
                    text=val.text,
                    on_release=self.cards_activities,
                )
                self.ids.search_list.add_widget(card)
            elif search_field.upper() in key:
                card = MD3Card(
                    source=val.source,
                    text=val.text,
                    on_release=self.cards_activities,
                )
                self.ids.search_list.add_widget(card)
```